# Input Radio gets deselected only for first element of array after Laravel Validation

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am doing project in laravel. I have same form for edit as well store. While edit/update its working perfectly but not for new entries (i.e for store/save). I have radio buttons  for user preferences, where user can choose only one time for a day. While doing this when I select 1st radio button then on laravel validation error(validation of other input fields) then that radio button gets deselected, but when I do this with second, third,etc then it works fine means it remains selected. Don't know what I am doing wrong.
 Here is my blade file.

```
@if(isset($selected_time))
    <input {{ !empty($selected_time['Monday'])? "checked=checked" : "null" }} name="time[Monday]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox pull-left" id="Monday" value="1">
@else
    {{ Form::checkbox('time[Monday]',true, isset($selected_time['Monday'])?in_array($selected_time,$selected_time['Monday'])?'checked="checked"':'null':null , ['class' => 'checkbox pull-left','id' => 'Monday']) }}
@endif
<label for="Monday">Monday</label>

@foreach($available_time as $time)
   <span class="time-slot">
   @if(isset($selected_time))
      {{ Form::radio('time[Monday][]',$time,isset($selected_time['Monday'])?array_search($time, $selected_time['Monday']) == 'null' ? 'checked' : '' : '', ['class' => 'input-Monday radio pull-left','id' => 'Monday['.$time.']']) }}
   @else
      {{ Form::radio('time[Monday][]',$time,isset(old('time')['Monday'])?array_search($time, old('time')['Monday']) == 'null' ? 'checked' : '' : '', ['class' => 'input-Monday radio pull-left','id' => 'Monday['.$time.']']) }}
   @endif
   <label for="Monday[{{$time}}]" class="timeslot">{{$time}}</label>
@endforeach
```

where my **$available_time** is,

```
'time'   => [
        '9AM-12PM'   => '9AM-12PM',
        '12PM-3PM'   => '12PM-3PM',
        '3PM-6PM'    => '3PM-6PM',
        '6PM-9PM'    => '6PM-9PM',
        '9PM-12AM'   => '9PM-12AM',

    ],
```

when I select Monday and time is 9am to 12pm then only it gets deselected.

**It's not working only for first element of $available_time**

[image]

Comment: and if you do save action and dump values sent what you get? Is monday in the list of selected? If not your value is not send.

Comment: I can see that it is selected as well as after validation when I dumped error bag then also I can see that monday and its time is selected. Just the checkbox is not getting selected only for 1st radio button

Comment: try change to array_search($time, $selected_time['Monday']) /// remove part  == 'null'.. because array_search return array or FALSE or change !== false

Comment: @daremachine tried this but no success...